# Cancelled spouse visa

Tags: visas, uk, moroccan-citizens, visa-cancellation

How can I know if my visa was cancelled by my partner or not?

I am Moroccan. He left me in Morocco in October.

Please help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Your question is not entirely clear.  To confirm: you are now in Morocco, and you have a UK visa, and you want to know whether it has been cancelled?  Normally, the only authority that can cancel a visa is the country that issued it, and the only other person who can request that is the visa holder (that is, you yourself).  So, three questions:  What is your partner's nationality?  What kind of visa is it?  Why and how do you think your partner may have cancelled it?

Comment: Are you sure that is a spouse visa? What does it say on your BRP?

Comment: My partner is British nationality .

Comment: My BRP is correct in all information .But he say he receive an email from home office .that say my brb got error ..now I want to now if I will have any problem if I want come to uk on my own ..i am in morocco since 2 october .

Answer (score 2):

Your partner/husband cannot cancel your spouse visa. A spouse visa is granted by the Home Office because of your relationship with your husband, spouse, or partner and gives you permission to stay in the UK for a specified period of time. A separation or divorce is classed as a ‘change of circumstances’ that enables the Home Office to decide whether or not to curtail or cancel your spouse visa.

You can use this service https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk to email or call UK Immigration. Your best option is to consult an Immigration lawyer in your country of residence, they will be able to make enquiries in your behalf.

Comment: Don’t bother with the UKVI helpline or email service. They are only allowed to read back information on the website. It’s a waste of money.